# Page on refresh returns blank with MIME errors on Angular 12 website version

Tags: javascript, angular, .htaccess, ionic-framework

i am having a problem with my pagers on a Angular 12 website project i did.

When i am refreshing the page [www.project.com/media/690](http://www.project.com/media/690) -690 is the id of the media or any other id- returns blank and i am getting these errors

```
    1934:1          GET http://localhost:8100/user/runtime.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
11Refused to apply style from '<URL>' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
1934:1          GET http://localhost:8100/user/polyfills.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
1934:1          GET http://localhost:8100/user/vendor.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
1934:1          GET http://localhost:8100/user/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
1934:51          GET http://localhost:8100/user/capacitor.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
1934:1          GET http://localhost:8100/user/styles.js 404 (Not Found)
1934:46 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8100/user/styles.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
1934:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8100/user/capacitor.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

If i refresh the page [www.project.com/media](http://www.project.com/media) (without any id) then the page refreshes fine. So, the problem is with the id.

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuard } from "./guards/auth.guard";


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch: 'full'},
//  { path: 'welcome', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/welcome/welcome.module').then(m => m.WelcomePageModule), canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'welcome', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/welcome/welcome.module').then(m => m.WelcomePageModule) 
  }, 
  { path: 'user/:id', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/user/user.module').then(m => m.UserPageModule) },
  { path: 'media/:id', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/media/media.module').then(m => m.MediaPageModule) },
```

same happens with user

link from another component to media page

```
goMedia(media: any) {
    media = media;
    this.userData.mediaViewed(media).pipe(
      map((data: any) => {
        if (data.success) {
          const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
            state: {
              media: media
            }
          };
          this.router.navigate(['media/' + media.msg_id], navigationExtras);
        }
      })
    ).subscribe()
  }
```

media page.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.activateRoute.paramMap.subscribe(params => {

      var id = params.get('msg_id');

      console.log(id);

    });
  }
```

my server adminstrator says its my fault and the server allows all MIME types for css or javascript.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

The MIME type errors are because the 404 (text/html) response is trying to be read as a JavaScript (application/javascript) file - which it is not.

The 404 responses would seem to be because you are requesting the URL `/user/` and you are using relative URLs in your HTML source, so the browser is (for example) requesting `/user/assets/icon/favicon.png` instead of `/assets/icon/favicon.png`, which I assume is the intention.

> ```
> <base href="./" />
> ```

It doesn't really make sense to have a *relative* BASE `href` here. This should be the URL that all other relative URLs are relative to. For example, if they should be relative to the root `/index.html` document:

```
<base href="https://example.com/index.html">
```

The `base` element is a "void element", so there should be *no* (self) closing tag.

You might be able to get away by simply removing the dot. ie. `href="/"`

Comment: thanks MrWhite. I am not getting an 404. and when i put <base href="https://example.com/index.html"> i am getting a blank page for every page.

Comment: The error i am getting its not for the favicon. i am using this   { path: 'user/:id', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/user/user.module').then(m => m.UserPageModule) },   to load the page. It goes ok and load the page but when i hit refresh i am getting a blank page

Comment: i edited to show the real problem

Comment: @simonloa did u fix that problem? cuz i face it today and i didn't know what to do and btw this is the first time that i have seen this problem